# Pi-Hole - DHCP static clients not resolving some hostnames

Tags: dhcp, dns

I am using Pi-hole as DNS (with unbound upstream) and for DHCP. I have mostly static DHCP reservations to keep the same IPS. Suddenly, I can't resolve some local hosts on the DHCP-served client machines. The resolution only works on the pi-hole itself. Before this, all DHCP served clients were automatically resolving for all other DHCP clients.

Now, it seems that the ones that won't resolve:

- Have a dash "-" in their hostnames
- Are usually turned off

However these resolve from the pi-hole but won't resolve, with or without a domain name from any other client. I have tried turning them on to renew their leases, rebooting the Pi-hole etc. Nothing works so far and this was all working fine for a while.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my provider turned DHCP back on on the router which of course messes things up. Disabled and it's working again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).